# The Ringer - A Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am right; I am left.
>   I am on; I am wrong.
>   I am winter; I am heat.
>   I am ahead; I am last.
>   I am play; I am serious.
>   I am wood; I am man.

What am I?

Comment: you are right, left, on, wrong, winter, heat, ahead, last, play, serious, wood and man

Comment: added the word tag for clarity.

Comment: "Thing" would work!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are

> Dead

Because

> I think all the sentences refer to commonly used idioms and expressions.

I am right;

> Dead right - right without doubt.

I am left.

> Left for dead - left in a situation where death is the most likely outcome.

I am on;

> Dead on - perfectly accurate, exactly right.

I am wrong.

> Dead wrong - completely wrong.

I am winter;

> Dead of winter - the middle of winter.

I am heat.

> Dead heat - a situation in which two or more competitors in a race are exactly level.

I am ahead;

> Dead ahead - straight ahead.

I am last.

> Dead last - exactly last.

I am play;

> Play dead - to pretend to be dead.

I am serious.

> Dead serious - completely serious.

I am wood;

> Dead wood - people or things no longer useful or productive.

I am man.

> Dead man - an object buried in or secured to the ground for the purpose of providing anchorage or leverage.

The Ringer

> Dead ringer - an exact lookalike.

Comment: Bingo! Well done.